# PhantomJS: When does onLoadFinished fire, and can it fire before external resources (like images) finish?

Tags: dom, phantomjs

I am loading some HTML into a WebPage object and listening for the "onLoadFinished" event. When the onLoadFinished is fired, I render the webpage to png.

The issue I'm seeing is that certain images in the HTML content consistently render when I use a SRC attribute like http://example.com/image.png, but do not render consistently when I use https://example.com/image.png in the SRC attribute (both SSL and non-SSL flavors are served properly when I access them via a browser).

Is the rendering problem due to a timing issue? Can onLoadFinished fire before images are loaded? If so, is there a clean way to verify that the images have been loaded before rendering to PNG?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed something similar with PhantomJS. When scraping links on multiple pages, sometimes it would fire onLoadFinished-event two times. One was too early, before all resources were served. My workaround was to wait status code for page on onResourceReceived and only after that do "onLoadFinished" when the right one fires (reject that one early call).

Comment: Interesting, I will have to check to see if that's part of the equation. Thanks for the tip.